# Unexpected Drools Ruleflow Behaviour

Tags: drools

Drools version: **6.5.0**

A rule flow sequence which takes (**Start -> A -> B -> End**) route, the expectation is all the rules in **A** (RuleflowGroup: A) will be executed first before all the rules in **B** (RuleflowGroup: B). But the result it produces from the implementation of the **AgendaEventListener** methods (i.e., beforeMatchFired, afterMatchFired) follows the reverse order. Rules associated with **B** are executed first before rules associated with **A**. 
Any explanation would be very helpful.

Please find the rule flow diagram below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same with version 7.x that i am currently using, it is because is a bit more complicated than you think. It is not just a flow. (A->B->C), is a stack.

So it is A then B/A then C/B/A. And when C finishes executing is returning back to B/A and then A.

If you want to get rid of that you can add a rule at last level, with lowest priority and
`eval (true)` in the when part and `halt()` in the then part to end the session before it returns to previous ruleflow group.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
Is this documented anywhere that the execution of ruleflow follows the LIFO structure? I searched for it in the drools documentation( https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch07.html). But seems like they mention only about the execution of rules, not the ruleflows.

Also, I tried to place the following rule at my .drl file, but does not seem like it is making any difference in the execution order. Am I doing it right?


rule "Last level"
 salience -1
 when 
  eval(true)
 then
  drools.halt();
end

Comment: Try this one [link](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e2058).
As it is mentioned here at 2.13.4.  
_RuleFlowGroups and AgendaGroups are merged:
These two groups have been merged and now RuleFlowGroups behave the same as AgendaGroups_

Later in 6.2.2.4. _Agenda Groups:
Agenda groups allow you to place rules into groups, and to place those groups onto a stack. The stack has push/pop bevaviour. Calling "setFocus" places the group onto the stack_
Your rule, seems right but they are a lot of things that can go wrong except ruleflowgroups.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Now that RuleFlowGroups and AgendaGroups are merged, official drools documentation should really be updated and make a clear statement about the LIFO style execution order for a sequence of Ruleflow groups. I came across a number of online posts asking for an explanation of this reverse execution order.